# Capturing the requested URL when an alias domain is the requested resource

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, redirect

I have a website  (example.com) that has a number of alias domains parked on it that used to have content on them. Most of that content is gone now. So when one of the alias domains gets requested with a deep link (alias1.com/this-used-to-be-here/) my 404 page is redirecting them back to (example.com)

What I would like to do is capture the root domain (alias1.com) or the entire URL path and append it in a way like example.com/?ref=alias1.com or if not possible to isolate the root the entire URL in that location.

My goal is track where the real users are coming from and dump the useless alias domains.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I tried this code but it returns "/404.shtml" at the end rather than the alias domain.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; 
URL='https://www.example.com/index.html?label=<!--#echo 
var="HTTP_REFERER" -->'" />
```

I would like to get the actual URL that was requested appended. I can use a 404.php instead if that makes it easier.

Comment: Take a look at the `$_SERVER` superglobal variable in PHP.

Comment: Would I use?

     header("Location: http://example.com/? 
     label=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ");
     die();

Comment: Nah, rather `HTTP_HOST` (if you want to get `alias1.com`)